# How to convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS to MM/DD/YYYY in snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to convert the date field from `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS` to `MM/DD/YYYY` format in a view using Snowflake database with below condition:

```
TO_VARCHAR(DATE(SRC_DATE),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I'm able to convert the date to expected format with above condition,  but when I try to load data from this view to different table using a sp its failing with below error:

> Failed: Code: 939 - State: 22023 - Message: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 1,058
> too many arguments for function [TO_VARCHAR(VALID_FROM_DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF9')] expected 1, got 2 - Stack Trace: Statement.execute, line 9 position 58

Need help in getting the right logic to fix this error. How can I do this?

Comment: What data type is your resulting object and what data type are you trying to write to in teh table?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
TO_VARCHAR(SRC_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I’m wondering why you are trying to change the format of a date in Informatica? A date is held as a number, the format is just how it is displayed - the underlying number doesn’t change

Comment: Thank for your response Nick. I'm not changing anything in Informtica. We just load the data from view to table. Also Informtica just a calls a sp that loads the data from view to target.

Comment: Also I tried using just TO_VARCHAR for date conversion function yet it failed with same error..

Comment: Hi - what is the datatype of SRC_DATE? If all you are trying to do is convert a timestamp to a date then you just need to truncate it - as long as everything is a DATE/TIMESTAMP datatype then format is irrelevant and you don’t need to worry about it. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trunc2.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's going on yet, but I can walk through some things we do know.

First, the error message says the `TO_VARCHAR()` function only expected one argument. Knowing this we can look at [the documentation for the method](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_char.html). Here we see there are several overloads:

```
TO_VARCHAR( <expr> )
TO_VARCHAR( <numeric_expr> [, '<format>' ] )
TO_VARCHAR( <date_or_time_expr> [, '<format>' ] )
TO_VARCHAR( <binary_expr> [, '<format>' ] )
```

Only one of these overloads (the first) fits the error message. Most of the overloads allow multiple arguments, but only if the first argument matches certain types: numeric, date/time, or binary. This *does* include the expected date result of the `DATE()` function

Therefore we can conclude somehow the result of the `DATE(SRC_DATE)` call is **NOT** a valid `<date_or_time_expr>` in every case, such that we at least sometimes end up with the first overload.

While [the documentation for `Date()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) does allow several ways for the function to return `NULL`, it also explicitly returns a Date type:

> The data type of the returned value is DATE.

Thus I'd still expect it to always match the third overload above. The only other possible result from `Date()` is the conversion fails, in which case we'd see a different error message entirely.

The best explanation I could guess at is the return type for `Date()` doesn't matter if the result is `NULL` (that is: `NULL` is inherently *untyped* for this purpose), such that you're still ending up with the first overload, which *does not allow the 2nd argument*.

You could possibly fix this by adding a `COALESCE()` so `NULL` is converted to a valid consistent throw-away date expression; something like, say, `1900-01-01`. If it's important to preserve `NULL` values you can then in turn also wrap the whole thing in a `NULLIF()` call.

Finally, all of this only make sense is `SRC_DATE` is not **already** a valid `<date_or_time_expr>`. That is, if it's something like a varchar column. This in itself would already be a mistake in schema design. On the other hand, if it *is* already a datetime column, there is no need at all to call `Date()`, and it can be used directly with `TO_VARCHAR()`... but with likely the same caveat about `NULL` values you're already seeing.

We can test this theory by trying the following:

```
TO_VARCHAR(DATE(IFNULL(SRC_DATE,'1900-01-01')),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have used the IFNULL condition for this SRC_DATE field and now it failed below error.
Logic: TO_VARCHAR(IFNULL(SRC_DATE,''),'MM/DD/YYYY')
Failed: Code: 100035 - State: 22007 - Message: Timestamp '' is not recognized - Stack Trace: Statement.execute, line 9 position 58

Comment: Use an actual date instead of an empty string for the 2nd IFNULL() argument.